# how can more than one thread execute my method?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

hey i'm sorry to be asking this here, but my lecturer won't help me with past exam paper answers. 
How can more than one thread execute my `oneTimeOnly()` method? and what steps would i need to take to make it thread safe/only executed once by one thread?

```
public class ExampleClass {
    private volatile boolean flag = false;
    public void someOperation() {
        if(flag != true) {
            oneTimeOnly();
        }
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: See the Java Tutorial on [Synchonization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Comment: Do you want it to be executed oneTimeOnly or by more than one thread? Or both?

Comment: want to ensure that oneTimeOnly is executed by only one thread please

Comment: You need to create multiple threads and in each thread's start method you can call this function. Make this function synchronized if you want this function to be called by only one thread at one time or if you just want a block, you can use a synchronized block inside function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a literal sense, nothing will prevent your method from being executed as many times as it is called. Only if understood on a higher level, the main logic of your method can be ensured to execute only once. I am saying this because some teachers/interviewers just love to nitpick and play meaningless mind games with their students/interviewees.

The problem with your approach is that two threads may be simultaneously executing your method, and setting `flag` to `true` only after both complete.

You can synchronize the method, or you can use an `AtomicBoolean` which can ensure that only one thread sets it to true. I believe this is too advanced for your class assignment, though, so stick with a `syncronized` method.

Comment: thanks. i'm still a little confused how 2 threads are accessing the method though..

Comment: Why, what exactly is bothering you? That is the nature of concurrent programming: two independent lines of execution may happen to enter the same method at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

you should declare your method as `synchronized`:

```
public synchronized void someOperation() { 
...
}
```

In this way you can be sure that only one thread at a time is executing your method's code, thus ensuring that the flag is set only once by the first thread calling it, and all other threads accessing it will find it already set.

Answer (score 1):

Make the method synchronized or use synchronized block like

public void synchronized oneTimeOnly(){}